# Pass custom HTTP headers to RESTful requests

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js, yii

I am trying to integrate Backbone in Yii and therefore I need REST. So I installed a Yii extension, [*restfullyii*](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/), which makes use of a username and password that need to be passed to requests. The problem is that I have no idea how to do this with Backbone.

Example of wanted request:

```
List
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X_REST_USERNAME: admin@restuser" -H "X_REST_PASSWORD: admin@Access" http://yii-tester.local/api/sample/    
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X_REST_USERNAME: admin@restuser" -H "X_REST_PASSWORD: admin@Access" http://yii-tester.local/api/sample/limit/1
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X_REST_USERNAME: admin@restuser" -H "X_REST_PASSWORD: admin@Access" http://yii-tester.local/api/sample/limit/10/5 (limit/offeset)
```

Current error response, which totally makes sense..:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "You are not authorized to proform this action.",
    "data": {"errorCode":500}
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to send such values throughout Backbone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone delegates its XHR requests to jQuery/Zepto, that's what you will have to modify.

The easiest solution is probably to provide defaults options via `$.ajaxSetup` and the [headers options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **headers(added 1.5)**
>   Default: {}
>
> A map of additional header key/value pairs to send along with the
>   request. This setting is set before the beforeSend function is called;
>   therefore, any values in the headers setting can be overwritten from
>   within the beforeSend function.

You would set it like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:{
        X_REST_USERNAME: "admin@restuser",
        X_REST_PASSWORD: "admin@Access"
    }
});
```

Every request sent will have the custom headers. See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/j5Rr4/

Or you could pass additional options to each requests, Backbone will forward them to jQuery:

```
var m = new Backbone.Model();   
m.fetch({
    headers:{
        X_REST_USERNAME: "admin@restuser",
        X_REST_PASSWORD: "admin@Access"
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/j5Rr4/2/

Finally, you could override Backbone.sync to add the headers for every request:

```
Backbone.realsync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    options.headers = {
        X_REST_USERNAME: "admin@restuser",
        X_REST_PASSWORD: "admin@Access"
    };

    return Backbone.realsync.call(model, method, model, options);
};

var m = new Backbone.Model();
m.fetch();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/j5Rr4/4/

Comment: The first option does not work no headers will be added, but it was a nice effort. The second option is not applicable for me, because I am fetching a collection and not saving a model. Do you got a suggestion for that as well?

Comment: @SjaakRusma Modified with a fetch, but that does exactly the same thing than $.ajaxSetup : add custom headers to the request. Inspect the fiddles with a console and you should see those extra headers.

Comment: Ajaxoptions did not work, adding the second editted option to m.fetch({ .. }); where m is the Collection, WORKED! Thanks!

Comment: @SjaakRusma Added a third solution that provides a global modification